# Does Earth also move due to some electrostatic forces?

Tags: electromagnetism, newtonian-mechanics, gravity, electrostatics

Does the earth experience some electrostatic forces due to other planets...which also make it move? 
My question is..whether the earth also moves due to electrostatic force of attraction or only due to gravity?

Answer (score 1):

The electrostatic forces acting on Earth are completely negligable because the net charge on Earth is relatively close the zero.

Comment: Daily..due to thunders..there is a huge amount of charge being induced on the surface of the earth..but is that still very less?

Comment: The charge difference may seem huge, but it really isn't enough to exert a significant force on a mass a large as a planet. Also, thunder storms are not due to Earth having a nonzero net charge, but are instead due to an uneven distribution of charge. To understand the differnence, I'd recommend reading a Wikipedia article on electric dipoles. The force exerted by an electric dipole is roughly proportional to the inverse cube of the distance, so it decreases very quickly and is not normally relavent in astronomical distances.

Comment: Okay...thanks for your answer mate..I read up on dipoles..!